# Array declared in main cannot be accessed in subsequent methods - Java

Tags: java, arrays, methods

I declared and initialized an array in my main method. I am unable to access the array in any subsequent methods within the same program. Is that normal?

Is there any way for me to be able to access an array in subsequent methods just by calling the array? Or would I have to declare and initialize the array again for every new method?

THANK YOU!

This is what my program looks like right now with my array declaration both inside and outside my main method.

```
 import java.io.*; 
 import java.util.*; 

public class useHamayelSajaEmployee 
{
    final int MAX_EMPLOYEES = 1000;
    HamayelSajaEmployee []emps = new HamayelSajaEmployee[MAX_EMPLOYEES]; 

    public static void main(String[]args) throws IOException 
    {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in); //scanner for reading from keyboard

        final int MAX_EMPLOYEES = 1000;
        HamayelSajaEmployee []emps = new HamayelSajaEmployee[MAX_EMPLOYEES]; 

        File file = new File("empList.txt");
        Scanner scan2 = new Scanner(file); //scanner for reading from file

        String divisionTitle = scan2.nextLine(); 
        int numOfEmps;

        for (int k = 0; k < 1000; k++) //for loop to set all the objects in array to constructor values
                    {
                        emps [k] = new HamayelSajaEmployee();
                    }

        int lastCount = 0; 

            while(!divisionTitle.equals("END_OF_FILE"))
        {
            System.out.println(divisionTitle + '\n');
            numOfEmps = scan2.nextInt();

            for (int i = lastCount; i < numOfEmps + lastCount; i++) //instead of starting from the 0 point and writing over the objects in array, starting from point we stopped with lastCount
            {
                HamayelSajaEmployee emp1 = new HamayelSajaEmployee();

                emp1.SetDivisionTitle(divisionTitle);

                String lastName = scan2.next();
                System.out.print(lastName + "\t" ); 
                emp1.SetLastName(lastName);

                String firstName = scan2.next();
                System.out.print(firstName + "\t");
                emp1.SetFirstName(firstName);

                int yearsInCompany = scan2.nextInt();
                System.out.print(yearsInCompany + "\t" );
                emp1.SetYearsInCompany(yearsInCompany);

                double salary = scan2.nextDouble();
                System.out.print(salary + "\t"  + "\t" );
                emp1.SetSalary(salary);

                String status = scan2.next();
                char status1 = status.charAt(0);
                System.out.print(status1 + "\t" );
                emp1.SetStatus(status1);

                String section = scan2.nextLine();
                System.out.println(section);
                emp1.SetSection(section);


                emps [i]= emp1;

            }
            System.out.println('\n'); //prints extra line between divisions for clarity
            divisionTitle = scan2.next();
            lastCount = numOfEmps + lastCount;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        { 
            if(!emps[i].GetDivisionTitle().equals("noDivsionTitle"))//so that no empty slots in array print
            {System.out.println(emps[i]);}
        }


        System.out.print("Enter 'M' to go to the Menu or 'Q' to Quit");
        String newPlace = scan.next();
        char newPlace1 = newPlace.charAt(0);


        if(newPlace1 == 'M' || newPlace1 == 'm')
        {menu();}

        if (newPlace1 == 'Q' || newPlace1 == 'q')
        {finalStats();}

        else
            {
            while (!(newPlace1 == 'M' || newPlace1 == 'm' || newPlace1 == 'Q' || newPlace1 == 'q'))
                {
            System.out.println("ERROR");
            System.out.println("Please try again.");

            System.out.print("Enter 'M' to go to the Menu or 'Q' to Quit");
            newPlace = scan.next();
            newPlace1 = newPlace.charAt(0);
            if(newPlace1 == 'M' || newPlace1 == 'm')
            {menu();}

            if (newPlace1 == 'Q' || newPlace1 == 'q')
            {finalStats();}
                }
            }

    }
```

This is what the other method looks like (I literally copy/pasted initialization and declaration of array from main into this one.

```
public static boolean listAll()
    {
        /* method meant to list all the employees names, years in company, salaries, statuses, and sections as read in from file*/
        File file = new File("empList.txt");
        Scanner scann = new Scanner(file);

        String divisionTitle = scann.nextLine(); 
        int numOfEmps;

        final int MAX_EMPLOYEES = 1000;
        HamayelSajaEmployee []emps = new HamayelSajaEmployee[MAX_EMPLOYEES]; 

        for (int k = 0; k < 1000; k++) //for loop to set all the objects in array to constructor values
                    {
                        emps [k] = new HamayelSajaEmployee();
                    }

        int lastCount = 0; 

            while(!divisionTitle.equals("END_OF_FILE"))
        {
            System.out.println(divisionTitle + '\n');
            numOfEmps = scann.nextInt();

            for (int i = lastCount; i < numOfEmps + lastCount; i++) //instead of starting from the 0 point and writing over the objects in array, starting from point we stopped with lastCount
            {
                HamayelSajaEmployee emp1 = new HamayelSajaEmployee();

                emp1.SetDivisionTitle(divisionTitle);

                String lastName = scann.next();
                System.out.print(lastName + "\t" ); 
                emp1.SetLastName(lastName);

                String firstName = scann.next();
                System.out.print(firstName + "\t");
                emp1.SetFirstName(firstName);

                int yearsInCompany = scann.nextInt();
                System.out.print(yearsInCompany + "\t" );
                emp1.SetYearsInCompany(yearsInCompany);

                double salary = scann.nextDouble();
                System.out.print(salary + "\t"  + "\t" );
                emp1.SetSalary(salary);

                String status = scann.next();
                char status1 = status.charAt(0);
                System.out.print(status1 + "\t" );
                emp1.SetStatus(status1);

                String section = scann.nextLine();
                System.out.println(section);
                emp1.SetSection(section);

                emps [i]= emp1;

            }
            System.out.println('\n'); //prints extra line between divisions for clarity
            divisionTitle = scann.next();
            lastCount = numOfEmps + lastCount;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        { 
            if(!emps[i].GetDivisionTitle().equals("noDivsionTitle"))//so that no empty slots in array print
            {System.out.println(emps[i]);}
        }

        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

An array declared locally in a method (such as your `main` method) can only be accessed in that method.

You can either :

1. make the array an instance or class member of your class, which will let other methods of your class have access to it.

OR

2. pass it as a parameter to any method that requires it.

To pass the array as a parameter :

```
public static void main(String[]args) throws IOException 
{
    ...
    HamayelSajaEmployee[] emps = ...
    ...
    listAll (emps);
}
```

Ans `someMethod` would look like this :

```
public static boolean listAll (HamayelSajaEmployee[] emps)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < emps.length; i++) { 
        if(!emps[i].GetDivisionTitle().equals("noDivsionTitle")) {
            System.out.println(emps[i]);
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: How would I pass I pass the array as a parameter? My array name is emps. Would I pass it like (emps [] )  when I declare my method? Thank You!

Comment: I have tried to pass  the array as a parameter, but I keep getting errors. Would the first part be in the main method and is someMethod allowed to be static?

Comment: @Shamayzing99 if the first part is in the main method than `someMethod` must be static.

Comment: I tried this while declaring the array outside of main like my code above but this error in next comment keeps coming up

Comment: useHamayelSajaEmployee.java:139: error: method listAll in class useHamayelSajaEmployee cannot be applied to given types;
   listAll();
   ^
  required: HamayelSajaEmployee[]
  found: no arguments
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
1 error

Answer (score 0):

This is pertinent to the concept of "scope." Take the following class:

```
public class SomeClass {
    int x = 3;
    public void SomeMethod() {
        int y = 5;
        if(x != y) {
            int z = x + y;
        }
    }
}
```

"x" can be accessed anywhere in SomeClass, y can only be accessed within SomeMethod, and z can only be accessed within that if statement. Think of it like this: When you declare a variable, it's only accessible within the tightest pair of {}'s around it. This is the basics of the concept of scope. Now, once you start playing with different variable modifiers (like "public"), you can start to alter the scope of a given variable/method.

To fix your issue of not being able to access an array created in one method in another method, I suggest declaring the array analogous to where "x" is in my sample class. Then it will be accessible throughout the class.

Here's an article on Oracle's website about access control and modifiers if you're interested, but it isn't necessary for this specific problem: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html

EDIT: Removed "static" modifier to SomeMethod so we weren't making a static reference to a non-static variable.

Comment: So I would have to declare and initialize my array before my main method?

Comment: You could declare it before the method, and then initialize it in the method itself.

Comment: I declared my array outside of main and then initialized it both inside of main and inside of my new method, but now this error keeps showing up: useHamayelSajaEmployee.java:236: error: unreported exception FileNotFoundException; must be caught or declared to be thrown
  Scanner scann = new Scanner(file);     
                   ^                                                                                     even though I declare a new scanner for each method.

Comment: Can you provide some code please? ...However, just from reading, you shouldn't initialize it twice, only once...and make sure you aren't trying to do any file processing outside of a method.

Comment: I added the code to my question and I just added the File and Scanner outside of my main and added public static in front of them and the same error for Scanner keeps coming up.